# Keep last 7 days in nlog

Tags: nlog

I want to keep last 7 days of files using nlog, but for some reason the following configuration in target=LogToShare is keeping only the latest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <variable name="WorkflowLoggingDirectory" value="${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}/Logs" />
  <variable name="LogSharedFolder" value="\\myserver\logs" />
  <rules>
    <logger name="WorkflowLogging" writeTo="LogToShare" />
    <logger name="WorkflowLogging" writeTo="WorkflowLogFiles" final="true" />
    <logger minLevel="Info" writeTo="EventLog" />
  </rules>
  <targets>
    <target type="File" 
        name="LogToShare" 
        layout="${time} ${level} ${message}" 
        fileName="${LogSharedFolder}\${machinename}_${shortdate}.log" 
        
        archiveFileName="${LogSharedFolder}\${machinename}_${shortdate}.{#}.log"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        archiveNumbering="Rolling"
        maxArchiveFiles="7"
            
        keepFileOpen="true" 
        openFileCacheTimeout="5" 
        concurrentWrites="true" 
        encoding="utf-8" 
        writeBom="true" />
    <target type="File" name="WorkflowLogFiles" fileName="${WorkflowLoggingDirectory}/${shortdate}_Execution.log" layout="${time} ${level} ${message}" keepFileOpen="true" openFileCacheTimeout="5" concurrentWrites="true" encoding="utf-8" writeBom="true" />
    <target type="EventLog" name="EventLog" layout="${processname} ${assembly-version} ${newline}${message}" source="UiPath" log="Application" />
  </targets>
</nlog>
```

The files in \\myserver\logs that are kept are only the files from the current day:

```
machine1_2020-08-09.log
machine2_2020-08-09.log
machine3_2020-08-09.log
machine4_2020-08-09.log
```

Tomorrow, the files that I will get are:

```
machine1_2020-08-10.log
machine2_2020-08-10.log
machine3_2020-08-10.log
machine4_2020-08-10.log
```

And the files from 2020-08-09 will be removed.

I'm using NLog v4.3.9. How can I keep the last 7 days of log?

Answer (score 1):

When using NLog 4.5 (or newer) then you can do this:

```
<target type="File" 
    name="LogToShare" 
    layout="${time} ${level} ${message}" 

    fileName="${LogSharedFolder}/${machinename}_${shortdate}.log" 
    maxArchiveFiles="7"

    keepFileOpen="true" 
    openFileCacheTimeout="5" 
    concurrentWrites="true" 
    encoding="utf-8" 
    writeBom="true" />
```

When using older NLog versions, then you can try this:

```
<target type="File" 
    name="LogToShare" 
    layout="${time} ${level} ${message}"          
   
    fileName="${LogSharedFolder}/${machinename}_${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
    archiveFileName="${LogSharedFolder}/${machinename}_{#}.log"
    archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
    archiveNumbering="Date"
    archiveEvery="Year"
    maxArchiveFiles="7"

    keepFileOpen="true" 
    openFileCacheTimeout="5" 
    concurrentWrites="true" 
    encoding="utf-8" 
    writeBom="true" />
```

Explanation of why the extra parameters are needed:

- **archiveFileName** - Using `{#}` allows the archive cleanup to generate proper file wildcard.
- **archiveDateFormat** - Must match the `${date:format=}` of the `fileName` (So remember to correct both date-formats, if change is needed)
- **archiveNumbering=Date** - Configures the archive cleanup to support parsing of filenames as dates.
- **archiveEvery=Year** - Activates the archive cleanup, but also the archive file operation. Because the configured `fileName` automatically ensures the archive file operation, then we don't want any additional archive operations (Ex. avoiding generating extra empty files at midnight).
- **maxArchiveFiles** - How many archive files to keep around.