# C# Nlog - How to rotate log files so it creates rotated logs file and archives

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, logrotate, log-rotation

I have a trouble with creating a following log rotation settings:

1 - Current log file (service.log)

10 - rotated logs file like service.1.log, service.2.log etc. Log files size are 10MB.

10 - archived logs

When the file reaches 10mb, we discard it with the name .1 when there are 10 such rotated files, the last one is archived and there are also 10 archives.

Example:

1. I have a log file - service.log. When the file reaches 10mb, we discard it with the 'service.1.log' name and create a new 'service.log' file. Then, when this situation is repeated, we discrad the log file with the 'service.2.log' name.
2. When there are 10 such rotated files, then the oldest one is archived and so we have the following situation: 1 - service.log (new created file); 9 files - service.2.log, service.3.log, .... service.10.log; 1 archived that was created from the 'service.1.log' file.
3. We should have also maximun 10 such archives. The oldest archives should be deleted.

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I even don't have an idea how to do it. Since all articles and examples that I've found show only how to enable creating an archive from logs. But that's not what I want.

Comment: Try to make an example of the archive-logic you want using 3 files (instead of 10). Like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63327005/193178

Comment: You can find different NLog FileTarget Archive Examples here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples

Comment: I didn't find an appropriate example.

Answer (score 0):

Think the closest option is `archiveNumbering="Rolling"`:

**Rolling**

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
    ...
    fileName="service.log"
    archiveFileName="service.{##}.log"
    archiveNumbering="Rolling"
    archiveAboveSize="10000000"
    maxArchiveFiles="10"  />
```

Example of file names (newest files first):

```
service.log
service.00.log
service.01.log
service.02.log
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples